# How to add API documentation from manual created routes and controllers in loopback 3?

Tags: node.js, swagger, loopback

This is RESTful API documentation that auto created by loopback from models. I need to add another API documentation from my manual added routes / controllers. Is it possible?
[Auto generated swagger API documentation by loopback 3 from models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJDPB.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "description" key in Remote Method Definition.

`Users.remoteMethod('getuserDetails', {
    isStatic: false,
    ** description **: 'Get user details using User-id. (for admin)',
    accepts: [{
      arg: 'data',
      type: 'object',
      description:'Description of data argument'
      required: true,
    }, ],
    http: {
      verb: 'post',
      path: '/user-details',
      ** description **:'Description endpint'
    },
    returns: {
      arg: 'result',
      type: 'object',
    },
  });`